# Best way to Persist Redis Bloom filter data?

Tags: redis, node-redis, bloom-filter

I am working on the Node.js application with Redis, for this application we have a mobile number and username existence check that I want to implement with the bloom filter. I came across https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom and I have used it in my application but worried about how would I persist my data if Redis shutdown my data would be lost. There is command BF.SCANDUMP and BF.LOADCHUNK but BF.SCANDUMP gives data in the unreadable form that may be in hexadecimal format.

I appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: RedisBloom persists the data using the native [Redis Persistence](https://redis.io/topics/persistence), so if you use these (RDB is enabled by default by the way) the data will survive restarts.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion sir, but I don't want the whole data to be persisted I just want my key to persisting.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to keep both persistent as well as non-persistent data in Redis, the recommended approach is to use a separate Redis server for each for of data